# Concept of Panchang Pranam in Buddhist culture

Tags: philosophy

What is Panchang Pranam in Buddhism and what is the correct way of doing it and its significance? Is it some sort of chanting?

Answer (score 2):

I found the term "*panchanga pranama*" on the wikipedia page for [*Praṇāma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pran%C4%81ma). In Indian culture and Hinduism, this simply means prostration with five parts of the body touching the ground.

[image: Praṇāma]

In the image above, the left person is doing *ashtanga pranama* (eight parts touching the ground - also known as full prostration) and the right person is doing *panchanga pranama* (five parts touching the ground - also known as half prostration).

This is common in Buddhism and is known to be practised since the time of the Buddha, for e.g. from [SN 22.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.001.than.html):

> Then the householder Nakulapita went to the Blessed One and on
> arrival, having bowed down to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting
> there he said to the Blessed One, "Lord, I am a feeble old man, aged,
> advanced in years, having come to the last stage of life. I am
> afflicted in body & ailing with every moment. And it is only rarely
> that I get to see the Blessed One & the monks who nourish the heart.
> May the Blessed One teach me, may the Blessed One instruct me, for my
> long-term benefit & happiness."

Both *ashtanga pranama* and *panchanga pranama* appear to be common in Tibetan Buddhism, as seen in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/QKVN4tb0moM), meanwhile *panchanga pranama* is common in Theravada Buddhism.

Apparently, in Pali, this is called *pañcanga-vandana*, which I found in the essay by Ven. Khantipalo entitled "[Lay Buddhist Practice: The Shrine Room, Uposatha Day, Rains Residence](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/khantipalo/wheel206.html)".

An example of reverentially reciting Pali incantations and prostrating respectfully before a Buddha image as described below, can be found in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/adpMTYPFELs?t=3757).

Ven. Khantipalo explained [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/khantipalo/wheel206.html):

> *Dhamma* is the way for training mind, speech and body. But the *Buddha
> dhamma* is sometimes regarded in a way which is too intellectual and
> theoretical so that there is a danger that it is not practiced as a
> way of training. To help with the training of the body there are
> various gestures which are expressions of one's confidence in and
> reverence for the three Treasures. These actions when performed with
> due mindfulness are wholesome *kamma* made by way of the body. Repeated
> frequently they become habitual bodily *kamma* and it is good to have
> the habit of reverence as part of one's character. The Buddha, soon
> after his Enlightenment, thought that to live without reverence was
> not suitable, so he looked around with the divine eye to find some
> teacher under whom he could live, revering him and his teachings. But
> he found no teacher superior to himself, nor any teaching superior to
> the *Dhamma* which he had discovered. But out of reverence for that
> *Dhamma* he decided to make the *Dhamma* his Teacher and to live revering
> *Dhamma*. We who are his followers should follow in his footsteps and
> live with reverence for those three aspects of Enlightenment: Buddha,
> *Dhamma* and *Sangha*.
>
> The gestures used for this are mainly two: respectful salutation with
> the hands (*añjalikamma*), and the five-limb prostration
> (*pañc'anga-vandana*).
>
> The first of these, which may be remembered as "*añjali*" as there is
> no satisfactory English equivalent, is made by bringing the palms of
> the hands together, and raising them to the region of the heart or
> higher, according to circumstances. For instance, in the shrine room
> after kneeling down in front of the Buddha image, one makes *añjali*
> before offering flowers, lights and incense. And as the Teacher was
> the highest in the world and one to go beyond the world, so one
> respects him by placing one's hand in *añjali* to the forehead. But
> while chanting, the hands are held in *añjali* at heart level. This
> action and others described here, should be done with mindfulness and
> therefore gracefully. And one should be careful to see that
> exaggerated and impetuous movements are avoided. As we remarked
> before, the *Dhamma* does not encourage unrestrained expressions of
> emotion, rather with its aid one endeavors to calm one's heart.
>
> After all these preliminary remarks, we have just got into our shrine
> room, knelt down, made *añjali* and offered the three offerings. Now
> there are flowers placed in their vases or upon some offering tray,
> candles or lamps burning brightly and a blue column of incense smoke
> rising to the ceiling. It is time to pay one's respects with the whole
> body to the Teacher. When afterwards one says "*Namo tassa...*" that
> word "*namo*" (homage) comes from the root *nam* meaning "to bend." So
> now one bends oneself, one's mind and body, down and acknowledges that
> the Buddha was indeed the Perfectly Enlightened One that one's own
> understanding of *Dhamma* is insignificant. In the kneeling position,
> one's hand in *añjali* are raised to the forehead and then lowered to
> the floor so that the whole forearm to the elbow is on the ground, the
> elbow touching the knee. The hands, palm down, are four to six inches
> apart with just enough room for the forehead to be brought to the
> ground between them. Feet are still as for the kneeling position and
> the knees are about a foot apart. This is called the prostration with
> the five limbs, that is the forehead, the forearms, and the knees.
> This prostration is made three times, the first time to the Buddha,
> the second to the *Dhamma*, and the third to the Noble Sangha.
>
> An ancient tradition from Thailand makes this more explicit as it adds
> a Pali formula to be chanted before each of the prostrations. Before
> the first one may chant:
>
> *Araham sammasambuddho bhagava*
> *Buddham bhagavantam abhivademi*.
>
> The Arahant, the Buddha perfected by himself, the Exalted One
> I bow low before the Exalted Buddha.
>
> Before the second prostration:
>
> *Svakkhato bhagavata dhammo*
> *Dhammam namassami.*
>
> The *Dhamma* well-expounded by the Exalted One
> I bow low before the *Dhamma*.
>
> And before the last one:
>
> *Supatipanno bhagavato savakasangho*
> *sangham namami.*
>
> The Sangha of the Exalted One's disciples who have practiced well
> I bow low before the Sangha.